# Pip has uninstalled itself but I do not know what caused it

Tags: python, cmd, pip

I was running pip2 install selenium, followed by pip2 install requests. I did something to my python scripts(i forgot what it was) but i went back to cmd after that and said pip was not recognised as an internal or external ... Is there any way I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to install something try:

```
python -m pip install [package name]
```

I tried that before and it worked for me, even when *pip was not found*.

Answer (score 0):

If you have truly uninstalled pip then you need to reinstall from the source. First you need to download the package.

`curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py`

Then you need to navigate to the folder where you just downloaded the package and run the script using your python interpreter.

`python get-pip.py`

or

`python3 get-pip.py`

This will also install wheel and setuptools if there are not there. Full instructions can be found at the pip website https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/